# Quick question about how strings work with strlen() and fgets()

Tags: c

I know that fgets() includes the newline character '\n' and that strlen() counts this as a character.

So for example, if I enter "Hello" into stdin and press my enter key, fgets() records that as "Hello\n"

This is considered a length of 5 according to strlen().

However, doesn't a string in C have to be terminated with the null character?

So in actuality, does fgets() record [H],[e],[l],[l],[o],[\n],[\0]?

Comment: This is directly answered in the manual page for `fgets`: "*`fgets()`  reads  in  at  most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer
       pointed to by `s`.  Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline.  If a newline is read, it  is  stored  into
       the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.*"

Answer (score 2):

> This is considered a length of 5 according to strlen().

No, it is considered 6 as `\n` is a normal character counted by the `strlen`

> So in actuality, does fgets() record [H],[e],[l],[l],[o],[\n],[\0]?

Yes, `fgets` forms a valid C string which includes the `null` termination character

You could easily test it yourself. Writing a small program takes same long as asking a question here, but the satisfaction if you discover it yourself is priceless. If you want to learn to program you need to experiment yourself.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str[32];
    

    memset(str, 0x77, sizeof(str));

    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    printf("str is %zu chalrs long : `%s`\n", strlen(str), str);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i ++)
    {
        printf("str[%zu] = 0x%02hhx `%c`\n", i, str[i], str[i] > 32 ? str[i] : ' ');
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fYEK1v

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose *If you want to learn to program you need to experiment yourself.*  This is partly true.  Learning to program well is a mixture of reading and maybe taking a class, practice and experimentation, and asking questions.  Sometimes (as here) performing an experiment is an excellent way of learning how something works, but sometimes, it is a terrible idea.  In particular, if you're having trouble figuring out what `i = i++ + ++i` does, please do *not* perform an experiment (at least, not one limited to one compiler).

Comment: @SteveSummit nowadays young peoplle cut corners and do not want to put any effort. If OP writes that `strlen("hello\n")` is  5 it means that he does not work on his own at all.

Answer (score 1):

> So for example, if I enter "Hello" into stdin and press my enter key, fgets() records that as "Hello\n". So in actuality, does fgets() record [H],[e],[l],[l],[o],[\n],[\0]?

Both those are correct. Assuming enough space is provided, `"Hello\n"` *is* stored, keeping in mind that it's a string (which *includes* the `\0` terminator).

> This is considered a length of 5 according to strlen().

Not quite, the length is 6 because `strlen` gives the character count up to but *not* including `'\0'`. It includes the `'\n'`.